# C to Pascal type conversion

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi, freepascal

Good day,

I work on I2C communication between Master (Raspberry pi 2B, using Lazarus) and Slave - Arduino Nano.
On Arduino I have defined

```
 typedef union
 {
   float Temperature;
   uint8_t bytes[4];
 } floatuint;
 floatuint fu;
```

On Raspberry pi I have defined

```
 TFloatUint = packed record
   case Boolean of
     False: (dabDouble: Double);
     True: (dabByte: packed array[0..3] of cuint8);
 end;
```

Using command

```
 count := FpRead(I2DeviceHandle, fl.dabByte, 4);
```

I receive the same values for byte array, but fl.dabDouble shows different result.

For example:

```
 fu.Temperature = 19.19;
 fu.bytes = (0, 128, 153, 65);

 fl.dabByte = (0, 128, 153, 65);
 fl.dabDouble = 2.6656892163191751e-314
```

Where I made a mistake?

Comment: Don't rely on a specific data format. Instead define a common exchange format (ASCII is still the best for floating point) and write serialisation functions/procedures for both sides. But in general, you not use floating point on such small MCUs like Arduino (includes the Cortex-M variants). Use fixed-point or fractional emulation via integers. That way conversion is much easier.

Comment: As you can see, communication goes using bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Double` is 8 bytes in size in pascal. use `Single` which is 4 bytes.

```
TFloatUint = packed record
   case Boolean of
     False: (dabSingle: Single);
     True: (dabByte: packed array[0..3] of cuint8);
 end;
```

Comment: Yes, that is solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

C `float` is a 4 byte single precision floating point type. Pascal `Double` is 8 byte double precision. You used the wrong type in other words. It should be:

```
TFloatUint = record
   case Boolean of
     False: (Temperature: Single);
     True: (bytes: array[0..3] of cuint8);
 end;
```

Note also that you should not pack the record. Not that it has any impact on the layout, but it will lead to the type having the wrong alignment value. And I see no reason to pack the array either.

For reasons unknown to me, Pascal programmers the world over seem to have a tendency to want to pack things that should not be packed.

Comment: Yes, that is solution. Thanks.